# Getting Response code = 406. Response message = Not Acceptable error when parsing JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I've built an Rails app that is called by another one (Rails as well), using ActiveResource.

The situation is that I expose the info from the first app as JSON as follows:

App 1:

```
class PromotionsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /promotions
  # GET /promotions.xml
  def index
    @promotions = Promotion.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json  { render :json => @promotions }
    end
  end
end
```

And I receive it on the App 2, through an ActiveResource model, as follows:

```
class Promotion < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "app_1_url"
  self.element_name = "promotion"
end
```

When I want to read the data as JSON, doing the following, I get 406 Not Acceptable error message:

```
class PromotionsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /promotions
  # GET /promotions.xml
  def index
    @promotions = Promotion.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @promotions }
    end
  end
end
```

But, when I try to parse the info as XML (doing the same as the code shown above, except for changing "json" for "xml" everywhere) it works.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the Content-Type header in App 2.. or maybe 1... but probably 2. Are you familiar with setting the headers of the ActiveResource? Maybe `self.format = json` ? I'm not familiar with ruby/rails

Comment: `self.format = :json` * http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#M001253

From looking at the documentation on format, it seems like XML is the default format if you haven't specified one, so that's why XML is working. You might need to specify that the format is JSON on both sides, although it seems like you may have done it on App 1 with `format.json { render :json => ....`

Comment: Cory, please post it as an answer, because it solved my problem :) BTW: I had to put it in App 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the format to JSON for the application that is receiving the data (App 2)

```
class Promotion < ActiveResource::Base
  #your code
  self.format = :json #XML is default
end
```

Here's how I went about figuring that out (for any googlers that end up here)

### Step 1: researching the error code

**[Per Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)**:
**406 Not Acceptable**
The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.
(Basically, the data you received is in a different language than you wanted)

---

### Step 2: diagnosing the problem

Because a 400 level error code is a Client error code, I determined that the error must have been with App 2 (in this case, app 2 is the client requesting data from app 1). I saw that you were doing some formatting for JSON in app 1 and looked for similar code in App 2 and didn't see it, so I assumed the error was with App 2 having a different **[Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)** header than App 1. The Content-Type basically tells applications/browsers what language each is speaking when they send/receive data. The value that you store in the Content-Type is the **[MIME Type](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm)** and there are lots of them.

You said that the XML type worked but JSON wasn't, so I checked the rails **[ActiveResource API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#M001249)** (used in App 2) looking for some headers or content-type method and saw a `format` method and property which matches what you used in the Action Controller for App 1. I also saw that the `format` is defaulted to XML if it is not supplied.

```
#Returns the current format, default is ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat.
def format
   read_inheritable_attribute(:format) || ActiveResource::Formats[:xml]
end
```

---

### Step 3: fixin thangz

add this line to the class in app 2:

```
self.format = :json
```

I'm sure you could adjust the Content-Type header with the headers method as well, but the API didn't have sample code displaying how to do that. Adjusting the Content-Type with the headers method would kind of just be the 'harder' way to do it, and because adjusting the Content-Type is so common rails created `format` to streamline the process. I saw that the API has [an example of adjusting the format attribute of the class that conveniently uses json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#M001248) and read that the `format` method/property "Sets the `format` that attributes are sent and received in from a mime type reference" aka sets the Content-Type HTTP Header.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CoryDanielson's answer.

Even when my application is using :xml format (which is as Cory noted set by default) I still had to include

```
self.format = :xml
```

in order to fix 406 error.